# What is the python vesion of this?

Tags: python, scripting

How would you do this in python?
(It goes through a file and print the string in between author": ", " and text": ", \ and then print them to their files)

Here is an example string before it goes through this:

`{"text": "Love this series!\ufeff", "time": "Hace 11 horas", "author": "HasRah", "cid": "UgyvXmvSiMjuDrOQn-l4AaABAg"}`

```
#!/bin/bash
cat html.txt | awk -F 'author": "' {'print $2'} | cut -d '"' -f1 >> users.txt
cat html.txt | awk -F 'text": "' {'print $2'} | cut -d '\' -f1 >> comments.txt
```

I tried to do it like this in python (Didn't work):

```
import re

start = '"author": "'
end = '", '

st = open("html.txt", "r")
s = st.readlines()

u = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
#print u.group(1)
```

Not sure if I'm close.

I get this error code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "test.py", line 9, in <module>
   u = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 146, in search
   return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or buffer`
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate *any* effort at solving this yourself?

Comment: Please create an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: "Didn't work" doesn't really mean anything. What *did* it do? Which part do you not understand well enough to try something else?

Comment: Your input is JSON; you should really be using the `json` module to process it, not regular expressions.

Comment: Why did this not cross my mind, thank you chepner. I know what I have to do now

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before getting into any of this: As chepner pointed out in a comment, this input looks like, and therefore is probably intended to be, JSON. Which means you shouldn't be parsing it with regular expressions; just parse it as JSON:

```
>>> s = ''' {"text": "Love this series!\ufeff", "time": "Hace 11 horas", "author": "HasRah", "cid": "UgyvXmvSiMjuDrOQn-l4AaABAg"}'''
>>> obj = json.loads(s)
>>> obj['author']
'HasRah'
```

Actually, it's not clear whether your input is a JSON file (a file containing one JSON text), or a JSONlines file (a file containing a bunch of lines, each of which is a JSON text with no embedded newlines).<sup>1</sup>

For the former, you want to parse it like this:

```
obj = json.load(st)
```

For the latter, you want to loop over the lines, and parse each one like this:

```
for line in st:
    obj = json.loads(line)
```

… or, alternatively, you can get a JSONlines library off PyPI.

---

But meanwhile, if you want to understand what's wrong with your code:

The error message is telling you the problem, although maybe not in the user-friendliest way:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 148, in search
    return _compile(pattern, flags).search(string)
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

See the docs for [`search`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) make clear:

```
re.search(pattern, string, flags=0)
```

> Scan through *string* looking for the first location where the regular expression *pattern* produces a match, and return a corresponding `MatchObject` instance…

You haven't passed it a string, you've passed it a *list of strings*. That's the whole point of [`readlines`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#file.readlines), after all.

---

There are two obvious fixes here.

First, you could read the whole file into a single string, instead of reading it into a list of strings:

```
s = st.read()
u = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), s).group(1)
```

Alternatively, you could loop over the lines, trying to match each one. And, if you do this, you still don't need `readlines()`, because a file is *already* an iterable of lines:

```
for line in st:
    u = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), line).group(1)
```

---

While we're at it, if any of your lines don't match the pattern, this is going to raise an `AttributeError`. After all, `search` returns `None` if there's no match, but then you're going to try to call `None.group(1)`.

There are two obvious fixes here as well.

You could handle that error:

```
try:
    u = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), line).group(1)
except AttributeError:
    pass
```

… or you could check whether you got a match:

```
m = re.search('%s(.*)%s' % (start, end), line)
if m:
    u = m.group(1)
```

---

<sub>1. In fact, there are at least two other formats that are nearly, but not quite, identical to JSONlines. I *think* that if you only care about reading, not creating files, and you don't have any numbers, you can parse all of them with a loop around `json.loads` or with a JSONlines library. But if you know who created the file, and know that they intended it to be, say, NDJ rather than JSONlines, you should read the docs on NDJ, or get a library made for NDJ, rather than just trusting that some guy on the internet thinks it's OK to treat it as JSONlines.</sub>